# Hibernate Windows with Wubi

Tags: windows-7, wubi, hibernate

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows7 using Wubi installer. I hear that Hibernation is disabled. 
My question is 
"Is hibernation disabled for Ubuntu only or for both Windows and Ubuntu?"

Comment: Hibernation is disabled in Windows if you or someone else have disabled it. It doesn't matter at all how you install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernation inside Ubuntu in WUBI would mess up your Windows system, so its disabled, but hibernation in Windows should stay the same unless you explicitly disable it.